# RT3290 Wireless still not working

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, wifi

I've been trying to get my wireless working for two weeks now. I have 1814:3290 wireless card. I am on Linux Mint 14 64-bit. I have tried all the suggestion on here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/240553/how-do-i-install-ra3290-bin-wireless-driver-into-lib-firmware

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2104129

https://askubuntu.com/questions/240553/how-do-i-install-ra3290-bin-wireless-driver-into-lib-firmware

I updated my kernel to 3.8.5-030805-generic. The first thing I tried was compiling the drivers (using original kernel 3.5.0-17-generic). When I compiled and installed, my wireless worked, but, I kept getting kernel panics every time I logged in. So I `modprobe -r rt3290sta`. After that I tried updating the kernel to the one I have now and copying the bin file. The kernel saw the wireless card but it was not active or anything. I checked `rfkill` and nothing was blocked. So then I tried compiling the drivers again after `make clean` first. Now when I try to compile the drivers I get this:

```
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:43:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:44:22: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_probe’
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:63:46: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘__devinitdata’
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:85:17: error: ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:86:17: error: ‘rt2860_probe’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:88:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘__devexit_p’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:88:29: error: ‘rt2860_remove_one’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:292:24: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_probe’
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:463:23: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘rt2860_remove_one’
/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.c:71:1: error: ‘__mod_pci_device_table’ aliased to undefined symbol ‘rt2860_pci_tbl’
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/pci_main_dev.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/dis/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.5-030805-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Everything is up to date also. I'm not sure where to go from here. Maybe I should downgrade my kernel to 3.6 or 3.7?

Edit: So I downgrade my kernel to 3.7.2 and recompiled the drivers. The kernel sees my wireless card but doesn't really seem to work and everything freezes. Going to try kernel 3.6.

Edit2: After more testing I found out that 3.7.2 and 3.6.11 both give me kernel panics after installing the wireless driver.

Edi3: I installed 3.7.11 and compiled and installed the wireless drivers. Wireless worked for 3 seconds and then had a kernel panic.

Answer (score 0):

I've bought a HP envy Dv7.
My Wireless was not working with native module and I was goting kernel panic with proprietary ralink rt3290 module.
So, I've found a solution at an Russian site (http://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=217802.0)

```
sudo su
apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r` build-essential --force-yes -y
cd ~
wget -c https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/15/compat-drivers-2013-03-15.tar.bz2
tar xvf  compat-drivers-2013-03-15.tar.bz2 | tail
cd compat-drivers-2013-03-15
scri*/dri* rt2x00
make
make install
```

So, blacklist your rt3290 module, "un-blacklist" both rt2800pci and rt2x00pci and reboot.
Everything is working fine to me now.