# How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working on Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, wifi

I have an HP Pavillion Touch 14-N009LA with a Ralink RT3290 wireless card running Debian Jessie with kernel 3.12.9-1. This distro looks as if the wireless drivers were included, and from another post [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71086/rt3290-wireless-still-not-working) it would look like it should work with the rt2800pci module, which is listed by lsmod and loads fine. However, whenever I issue `ifconfig wlan0 up`, I get `SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such file or directory`. I tried using the kernel.org compatibility sources from the previously linked post and they didn't work, after installing them I can't load the module and I must uninstall them and use the Debian-bundled module. I tried compiling the driver's sources from [this other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) and they don't compile. I'm not sure if downloading the binary archive linked on that thread will be a good idea given that that one is for Ubuntu and I'm running Debian Testing. I tried to apply [this fix here for Arch/Gentoo](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=56439) but couldn't find the right file.

Following the third link I managed to diagnose this situation a little, this is what I get from running `dmesg` right after attempting to bring up `wlan0`:

```
[ 4374.981101] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt3290.bin'
[ 4374.981132] rt2800pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load rt3290.bin (-2)
```

So basically, it looks like I *have to* get the drivers to compile. I have `build-essential` and `linux-headers-amd64` for my running version of the kernel, tried with `HAS_WPA_SUPPLICANT=y` and `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT=y` as well as with only `HAS_NATIVE_WPA_SUPPLICANT_SUPPORT` on, and this is what I get:

```
black@rockshooter:~/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508$ make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/tools'
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.12-1-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘duplicate_pkt’:
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:508:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pHeader802_3, HdrLen);
   ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:111,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/kernel.h:14,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/time.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/os/rt_linux.h:18,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_os.h:42,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_comm.h:56,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
 void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
       ^
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:510:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘memmove’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   NdisMoveMemory(skb->tail, pData, DataSize);
   ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/string.h:17,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/dynamic_debug.h:111,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/kernel.h:14,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/cache.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/time.h:4,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/stat.h:18,
                 from /usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/os/rt_linux.h:18,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_os.h:42,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_comm.h:56,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-common/arch/x86/include/asm/string_64.h:58:7: note: expected ‘void *’ but argument is of type ‘sk_buff_data_t’
 void *memmove(void *dest, const void *src, size_t count);
       ^
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘ClonePacket’:
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:662:20: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   pClonedPkt->tail = pClonedPkt->data + pClonedPkt->len;
                    ^
In file included from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_os.h:42:0,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/rtmp_comm.h:56,
                 from /home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:35:
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘RtmpOsPktInit’:
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/include/os/rt_linux.h:992:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   ((RTPKT_TO_OSPKT(_pkt))->tail) = (PUCHAR)((_start) + (_len))
                                  ^
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:681:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL’
  SET_OS_PKT_DATATAIL(pRxPkt, pData, DataSize);
  ^
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘wlan_802_11_to_802_3_packet’:
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:708:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  pOSPkt->tail = pOSPkt->data + pOSPkt->len;
               ^
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c: In function ‘__RtmpOSFSInfoChange’:
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1136:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsuid = current_fsuid();
                    ^
/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.c:1137:20: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int’ from type ‘kgid_t’
   pOSFSInfo->fsgid = current_fsgid();
                    ^
make[4]: *** [/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [_module_/home/black/WA/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux] Error 2
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.12-1-amd64'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Debian 8: You need the non-free package [firmware-ralink](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-ralink).

`apt-get install firmware-ralink`

In Debian 9: Non-free package is [firmware-misc-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-misc-nonfree).

`apt-get install firmware-misc-nonfree`

Check also [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb).

Comment: Tried it and it worked like a charm, thanks. Didn't think the solution was so simple ^^U;

Answer (score 0):

So... this is really bizarre, and I can't guarantee it will work, but it worked for me and I wanted to put this information somewhere that a lot of people would end up seeing it and have something to try if they still can't get their rt3290 working.

I couldn't get the rt3290 working for the life of me under Debian Squeeze, no matter what I tried, installing the firmware-ralink package, trying to compile the drivers manually (to no avail because of missing dependencies that cause problems if forced into the system), etc.

I bought a TP-Link wireless dongle, confirmed to work with Linux, so that I could have wireless on my laptop again.

I installed these drivers: http://www.tp-link.us/res/down/soft/TL-WN725N_V2_150911.zip

... and now my rt3290 works perfectly...? Quelle surprise!

Yeah. I don't get it either. I don't really have a lot of data with which to back up my answer other than the fact that my dongle is sitting unplugged next to me and I am connected with my rt3290, but if someone else 'solved' the problem this way, I would have loved to have seen this bizarre solution somewhere while I was struggling. So if there's anyone out there still having the same troubles I am, I hope you find this answer by way of google and give the TP-Link drivers a try.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using debian 8 or debian 9, as well as ubuntu from 16 the drive will already be installed. The problem is that the drive can't handle the name that's given the interface. For the drive to work just rename the card. in the file "/ etc / default / grub" change lines so that it looks like this: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX = "net.ifnames = 0 biosdevname = 0" then run the following command: sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg That's just restart the machine. That the drive will be working.